# SQL Select Row from page ID

Tags: php, sql, database, row

I am trying to populate a page thats created with a ( port_id=$project ). The single-post page works and it is getting populated but by the WHOLE table instead of just the Row with the same ID. 
here is my code from the single page:

```
$db = dbconnect('test');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM portfolio'; 
$result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$currportfolio = $_GET['port_id'];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$project = $row['port_id'];
echo "
<div class='post-img bottom-50'>
<h3 class='bottom-20'><a href='blog-single.html'>Consectetur adipisicing elit</a></h3>
<div class='proj-img1 bottom-20'>             
<a class='prettyPhoto zoom' href='upload/".$row['image']. "'>
<img src='images/content/portimg.jpg' alt=''></a>
</div>
<p>".$row['description'] . "</p>
</div>
</div>
";}
```

Comment: I think the SELECT should  have a WHERE clause to match the id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should could call the $currportfolio  variable first, and then add it into the query

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE port_id = $currportfolio ';
```

Then you are only calling the values from that specific row.

Comment: im pretty new at this - I moved the $currportfolio = $_GET['port_id']; before the sql =  and then added the WHERE id = $currportfolio but that didnt work, not populating any content.

Comment: what is the name of your column? Is it `port_id`? if so make it 

WHERE port_id = $currportfolio

Comment: AH!! haha got it - you are awesome I had a different ID name 

Thank you so much!